Execution Revert on Chainlink Function Send Request
This is the smart contract
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/dev/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/dev/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";

/**
 * @title Chainlink Functions example on-demand consumer contract example
 */
contract FunctionsConsumer is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
  using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;

  bytes32 public donId; // DON ID for the Functions DON to which the requests are sent

  bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
  bytes public s_lastResponse;
  bytes public s_lastError;
 string public source;
  constructor(
    string memory _sourceCode,
    address router,
     bytes32 _donId) FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
    donId = _donId;
     source = _sourceCode;
  }
function getsource()public view returns(string memory){
return source;
}
  /**
   * @notice Set the DON ID
   * @param newDonId New DON ID
   */
  function setDonId(bytes32 newDonId) external onlyOwner {
    donId = newDonId;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Triggers an on-demand Functions request using remote encrypted secrets
   * @param args String arguments passed into the source code and accessible via the global variable `args`
   * @param bytesArgs Bytes arguments passed into the source code and accessible via the global variable `bytesArgs` as hex strings
   * @param subscriptionId Subscription ID used to pay for request (FunctionsConsumer contract address must first be added to the subscription)
   * @param callbackGasLimit Maximum amount of gas used to call the inherited `handleOracleFulfillment` method
   */
  function sendRequest(
    string[] calldata args,
    bytes[] calldata bytesArgs,
    uint64 subscriptionId,
    uint32 callbackGasLimit
  ) external onlyOwner {
    FunctionsRequest.Request memory req; // Struct API reference: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/api-reference/functions-request
    req.initializeRequest(FunctionsRequest.Location.Inline, FunctionsRequest.CodeLanguage.JavaScript, source);
    if (args.length > 0) {
      req.setArgs(args);
    }
    if (bytesArgs.length > 0) {
      req.setBytesArgs(bytesArgs);
    }
    s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(req.encodeCBOR(), subscriptionId, callbackGasLimit, donId);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Store latest result/error
   * @param requestId The request ID, returned by sendRequest()
   * @param response Aggregated response from the user code
   * @param err Aggregated error from the user code or from the execution pipeline
   * Either response or error parameter will be set, but never both
   */
  function fulfillRequest(bytes32 requestId, bytes memory response, bytes memory err) internal override {
    s_lastResponse = response;
    s_lastError = err;
  }
}```

and this is the script
 
const { abi, bytecode } = require("../contracts/abi/FunctionsConsumer.json");
const { wallet, signer } = require("../connection.js");
const { networks } = require("../networks.js");
const { ContractFactory, utils } = require("ethers");
const { Location } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const NETWORK = "ethereumSepolia";

const routerAddress = networks[NETWORK].functionsRouter;
const donIdBytes32 = utils.formatBytes32String(networks[NETWORK].donId);

const deployFunctionsConsumerContract = async () => {
  const contractFactory = new ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet);

  const source = fs
    .readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../source.js"))
    .toString();

  console.log("\n Sending the Request....")
    
  console.log(
    `\nDeploying FunctionsConsumer contract on network ${NETWORK}...`
  );
  const functionsConsumerContract = await contractFactory
    .connect(signer)
    .deploy(
      source,
      routerAddress, donIdBytes32);

  await functionsConsumerContract.deployed();
  console.log(`\nDeployed at address ${functionsConsumerContract.address}`)
};

deployFunctionsConsumerContract().catch(err => {
  console.log("Error deploying the Consumer Contract ", err);
})

But I am facing issue when sending request. where do you think the issue can be?

const postData = {
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{ role: "user", content: gptPrompt }],
  temperature: 0,
};

const openAIResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer <pass-key>`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  data: postData,
});

if (openAIResponse.error) {
  throw new Error(JSON.stringify(openAIResponse));
}

const result = openAIResponse.data.choices[0].message.content;

console.log(result);
return Functions.encodeString(result);

and this is the source i am not using any secret key

So, after deploying your contract, have you added its address as a consumer?

yes created subscriptionId:3042

Okay, so you’ve added this contract as a consumer. And, are you facing that error while calling the sendRequest of this contract only?

yes exactly everything i did

Can you show the script of your sendRequest function call? Or, if you’re calling it via block explorer or so, then what arguments are you passing?

  const args = [prompt];
  const callbackGasLimit = 250000000;
  const subscriptionId = "3042";

  console.log("\n Sending the Request....")
  const requestTx = await functionsConsumer.sendRequest(
    args,
    [], // bytesArgs can be empty
    subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit
  );```

sorry for late reply this is the parameter

What is the error you're getting? Is it an error in executing sendRequest() or is it an error during 'fulfillment' - i.e. when returning the functions-executed JS result back into your smart contract?

As, you've mentioned:

i am not using any secret key

The problem is that you've to use the API key as a secret, because OpenAI API that you'e using (i.e., https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions) is authorised with the corresponding API key.
You can get the OpenAI API key by registering on their API dashboard.
